# In Dragon Age, how can you get Morrigan to come with you with Isabela in the Pearl?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

If you go to the Pearl, you can get Isabela to give you Dueling lessons by either playing cards or having a bit of .. fun.. on her ship. How can you get Morrigan to join in?

I've got her as interested, but she doesn't seem to want to go. Does she need to be hardened or something? If so, how can I harden her?

Comment: It's far more fun to take Leliana and Zevran with you to meet Annabel.

Comment: @Jeffrey Ooohhh yeah....

Comment: "Harden." That's... an interesting thing about Morrigan that I don't think I ever really needed to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible, I had Leliana joining but there was a black screen so it was not so much fun...

Maybe Morrigan must loves you for joining.
Howewer you are losing nothing. Really :P

Answer (score 4):

I do not believe it is possible.  According to http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Isabela, as a male character you can only bring Leliana (and only if she is hardened) and/or Zevran to join in the fun.  As a female you can bring Alistair (if hardened), Leliana (if hardened), and/or Zevran.

The Last Doctor is correct about the event - there is nothing to see other than a fade-to-black screen when you choose to have a bit of fun on her ship...